# Progress bar during mining in Solidity-Ethereum

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar, ethereum, solidity

Question is very simple , but answer ... no idea !!

so question is
how to show a progress bar using bootstrap on html page while the mining is going on in geth till it ends.

As and when the mining happens the progress bar must show the progress and show 100% and vanish after successful mining or transaction.

can we do this ?

Comment: Please show us code examples and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Given that mining or finding a block is a "lottery", there is no a "deterministic" way that you can based your progress bar on top pass from 0 to 5% for instance.

It's like asking how to handle a progress bar that bruteforce a hashed password.

Comment: i have used gif image connected to the transaction completion to achieve solution for this.
thanks you

Answer (score 0):

While @onepix' answer is true in general you can not predict the time till the next block is found. However, what you can do is to use a progress bar which expects a new block every 15 seconds and just counts the seconds from the last block to calculate the percent.

To get the latest timestamp from web3:

```
let tlast = web3.eth.getBlock(web3.eth.blockNumber).timestamp;
```

To get the current timestamp:

```
let tnow = Date.now() / 1000.0;
```

And to calculate the percent, do the math based on the 15 seconds target:

```
let perc = (tnow - tlast) / 15.0 * 100.0;
```

The result will be a positive value in `%`, but note if no block is found, it will exceed 100%. You can decide on your own how to deal with values for `perc >= 100`.

Comment: Found an alternative solution myself.
Tracking the transaction i have added a GIF image. Made the gif display till the successful transaction is done. Thanks for response